# How to delete only files in a folder and its subfolders

Tags: file, batch-file, subdirectory

I have a batch script to delete files in a given folder:

```
@echo off 
:: set folder path 
set dump_path=C:\REPORTS\TEMP
:: set min age of files and folders to delete 
set max_days=0
:: remove files from %dump_path%
echo "REMOVE FILES " %date% %time% >>C:\REPORTS\LOGBATCH\logfile.log
forfiles -p %dump_path% -m *.* -d -%max_days% -c "cmd /c del /q @path && echo @path>>C:\REPORTS\LOGBATCH\logfile.log" 
echo "END REMOVE FILES " %date% %time% >>C:\REPORTS\LOGBATCH\logfile.log
```

How can I extend it to remove files from subfolders?

Comment: When you were reading the help file for the `FORFILES` command did you accidentally gloss over the `/S` option?

Comment: did you notice `forfile`'s `/s` switch?

Comment: thank you all for help!

Comment: Also, please do not get into the habit of using broken labels to prefix lines intended as remarks, **`::`**. There is already a command specifically for that purpose, `REM`.

Comment: I would also advise that you get into the habit of using this recommended syntax for defining variables, `SET "var=value"`, and using either this syntax, `(ECHO String) 1>> "output.ext"`, or this one `1>> "output.ext" ECHO String` for `ECHO`ing strings to a file. You should also, for safety, doublequote `%dump_path%`.